# What is the value of the limit?

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I need to solve the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x}$$

If I replace $x$ with $0$ I get $\frac00$ so that is not what I should do. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Consider the limits with $x\to 0^+$ and $x\to 0^-$ and apply the substitution $x=\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: $$\lim_{z\to \pm\infty} z e^{-z^2} = 0 $$

Comment: I think that if x is smaller or greater than 0 does not matter cause it says to show that those limits are equal.

Comment: That is right *a posteriori*. For instance, the similar limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x}$ does not exist, since the limits as $x\to 0^+$ and $x\to 0^-$ differ. You have to rule out such phenomenon.